# iOS 7: Restrict device current orientation when modal view controller is presented

Tags: cocoa, ios7, popover, screen-rotation

I have a UIViewController which contains a UICollectionView. On tapping any of the UICollectionViewCell I present a modal view controller.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
PopViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailsView"];
vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
vc.transitioningDelegate = self;
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The PopViewController shows up correctly. Now I want to restrict the device orientation when PopViewController is being presented. That is if PopViewController is presented in portrait mode then it should not change to landscape even if I switch to landscape mode (using Rotate Left or Right in simulator) until I dismiss the  PopViewController.

I have used following code in PopViewController:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
```

What else (or instead) is needed to lock the pop up view to the current orientation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your modal controller try to add this, also (iOS > 6)

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
         return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

to support iOS 5 or below you must additional add:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{

   return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);

}
```

Comment: C'mon!!! Try this example https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19438780/testRotate-portrait.zip

Comment: Your app is working fine. My app also works fine when I use segue to present modal controller, but it doesn't work when I use presentViewController method.

Comment: check my example with presentViewCtrl: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19438780/testRotate-portrait2.zip

Comment: Once again your app is working fine. Guess I must be making some mistake somewhere, will figure out that. Thank you for your help though, at least now I know my approach is not incorrect.

Comment: If "the above" helped you, you can accept the answer (the little green sign) :) Happy coding!